# Fetch numbers only from an address column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Actually in my case I need to select street number from a address string, which means if the string is '`1234 dummy789 road`', I only want to get '`1234`', not '`1234789`' Another example is '`Plot 111 dummy 1220`' then i want only '`111`'. and if the string is '`111/2 dummy`' then i want to get '`111/2`'

I tried following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN substr(address , 1, 1) between '0' and '9'
              THEN substr(address , 1, 1)
            ELSE 'False'
       END as add
from test
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to have a go at it yourself, and tell us what went wrong, and then we can help you get over the parts that are troubling you... so - have a go, and when you have, edit your question and show us the code you tried (even and especially if it's not working), and then we can begin to help you out :)

Comment: Thanks #jarlh and #Taryn East

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        $ab = "1225584454 red 1555  blue";
        $result = explode(" ", $ab, 2);
        print_r($result);
    ?>
```

[image: Screenshot of the values]

in this case this will gives you first string in your variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want sql not in php.
And it fails when the string is "red 1555  blue"

Comment: you can use this before sending data to database.??

Comment: I'm fetching data from the DB, I want first occurrence of integer or number in an address column from a table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have civil number followed by space and street name I would suggest the following:
Put WHERE statement with REGEXP to get those, which start with digit-followed-by-space. And in returned field get only numeric portion with substring.

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(address, 0,  LOCATE(' ', address)) FROM items WHERE `address` REGEXP '^[0-9]+ '>0;
```

Correction:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEFT(address, LOCATE(' ', address))) FROM items WHERE `address` REGEXP '^[0-9]+ '>0;
```